# SFML game only runs smooth at high framerate (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate, fixed-timestep

I am trying to make my game smooth on low and high fps. Right now, it only runs smooth when I don't limit the framerate. If I run it at 60, then my sprite is noticeably "sluggish". I believe this happens because of the FPS spikes like crazy. It goes from 20-65 FPS and sometimes to the thousands.

I tried to implement a fixed timestep as per this tutorial: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/, which made it better. However, you can still notice that it is not smooth if the framelimit is limited.

So it only runs smooth like this:

```
window.setFramerateLimit(0);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);
```

Otherwise, it doesn't.

I do believe, though, this is only being caused on Windows 10. I had someone try it on their Linux machine with a Nvidia graphics driver and they said it ran smooth even with a framelimit. I have a Nvidia graphics driver as well but my OS is Windows 10.

Here's the code:

Game.h: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4dce9df0ee983016466f19d4fd43940d

Game.cpp: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9724aa1336c231b3cf96b726316ba14b

Player.h: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/610ffaecdd85c741058afec32eace912

Player.cpp: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf0a6e3e7ffaeaa39088a6e92c069556

Whole project (6 files with code): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/735021/Spritesheet.zip

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're not updating your player position every frame, but instead you're only updating it when timePerTick is used. This makes your scene update slower then you'd expect. Good plan is to change "direction" of the player every time timePerTick happens, but you should update players position _every frame_, i.e. move it forward to the direction requested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried doing this, but I got the same effect. I pass the `frameTime.asSeconds()` to a Player method called `move(float frameTime)` and change the `crntPosition` in there. I call `move()` outside of the while loop that checks the ticks. Did I do something wrong?